# Does Dapper support c# 6 read-only properties in POCOs?

Tags: dapper, c#-6.0

Given the following:

```
public class SomePoco {
    public int IntValue { get; }
}
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE SomePocoStorage (IntValue INT NOT NULL)
```

and

```
INSERT SomePocoStorage VALUES (1), (274)
```

If I call

```
connection.Query<SomePoco>("SELECT * FROM SomePocoStorage")
```

does Dapper handle populating the `IntValue` field on the returned `SomePoco` instances?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Good question! It isn't a scenario I've targeted, but I'd be more than happy to take a look at what would be involved. Since we already do a lot of nasty reflection, this could still be viable. Probably better as a github issue, but I'll have a look.

Update - [*it does now*](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/bebe80bcaff983433ea8043f3e432fd191915035) (at the current time, via repo only - not deployed):

```
[Fact] // passes
public void GetOnlyProperties()
{
    var obj = connection.QuerySingle<HazGetOnly>(
        "select 42 as [Id], 'def' as [Name];");
    obj.Id.IsEqualTo(42);
    obj.Name.IsEqualTo("def");
}
class HazGetOnly
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; } = "abc";
}
```

Comment: I opened issue #473 on the GitHub project.

Comment: @arootbeer I already changed the code... will be in next build

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No because there's no way for Dapper to set the value of the property if that property only has a getter.

Comment: Historically it didn't, simply because it hadn't been coded to support it. However - see my answer: it now works. This is actually not very hard to do.

Comment: Very nice Marc! Are you a contributor by any chance? If you are, I actually wrote a lightweight ORM that I extended from Dapper. I would love for you to take a look at it and give me your honest opinion on it as I'm trying to improve myself as a software engineer. The link is https://www.github.com/RiceRiceBaby/ADOCRUD. Thanks!

Comment: I'm the primary author and maintainer. I will try to have a look at your repo.

Comment: Very cool! Excellent work on Dapper. I've implemented it on many of the web apps I've worked on and have always tried to promote it to my other developer friends. It saves so much time. Keep up the great work!