# readonly POCO that always represents database state

Tags: c#, dapper, poco

As of Dapper 1.50.5 this feature has been added to allow readonly properties (getter, no setter) to be set by Dapper:

> [Does Dapper support c# 6 read-only properties in POCOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634434/does-dapper-support-c-sharp-6-read-only-properties-in-pocos)

This is good because I want objects never modified by anything except the constructor. (So I don't want setters)

Now I have a situation where I want to create an object by specifying an id in the constructor, and then Dapper populates the properties. However, Dapper still requires either a parameterless constructor, or one that specifies every property.

I don't want to expose a constructor that has the potential to make an object that is not a exact representation in the database (A object with uninitialized properties, or one that is given false information).

Because Dapper doesn't allow this, there must be a better way on what I am trying to accomplish. I also feel like the code is just not quite right. I want a POCO to always represent state (assuming db hasn't change since creation) and have it be **impossible** to modify or get it not to represent database state. How can I accomplish this?

Note: I understand that because what I want is Dapper to circumvents all my constraints that someone could just use dapper and create a `FooBar` that is a misrepresentation of the database, but that is an acceptable instance.

Here is psuedo-code what I would like (but does not work)

```
public class FooBar
{
    public FooBar(int id) {
        var sql = ""select * from FooBar where id = @id";
        var obj = connection.QuerySingle<FooBar>(sql, new {id});
        this.Id = obj.Id;
        this.Name = obj.Name;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps mark the constructors `internal` instead of `public`. Then move your objects to their own assembly/DLL, so the rest of the program can't construct them at all. Now the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute can give Dapper access to see it's required constructors.

This, in combination with the factory pattern to expose safe ways to construct the objects to the rest of the program, might accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this much freedom to accommodate creating a new assembly, unless there is a way to assign certain classes to their own assembly but have them remain in the same project.